# Not able to upload images with php correct

Tags: php, html

So I have a php script where I upload a image from a html form. The php file looks like this:

```
<?php
function generateRandomString($length = 10) {
$characters = 
'0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
$charactersLength = strlen($characters);
$randomString = '';
for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
    $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
}
   return $randomString;
}


$herman_is_the_best;

if(isset($_POST["place"]) && isset($_POST["submit"])) {
$herman_is_the_best = $_POST["place"];


$target_dir = "../places/" . $herman_is_the_best . "/" ;
$realtarget = $target_dir . generateRandomString() . "." . 
pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image





//check if there is a folder for the location alredy
$direction = "../places/" . $herman_is_the_best . "/"; 
if(!is_dir($direction)){
//make direction for place
mkdir($direction);


// url encode the address
$address = urlencode($herman_is_the_best);

// google map geocode api url
$url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=". $address ."&key=AIzaSyDeqk1Oc6TkKQkQph_-P_4U9jTLLJv0G98";

// get the json response
$resp_json = file_get_contents($url);

// decode the json
$resp = json_decode($resp_json, true);

// response status will be 'OK', if able to geocode given address 
if($resp['status']=='OK'){

    // get the important data
    $lati = $resp['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lat'];
    $longi = $resp['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lng'];

    // verify if data is complete
    if($lati && $longi){

        // put the data in the array
        $data_arr = array();            

        array_push(
            $data_arr, 
                $lati, 
                $longi
            );

    }

}

$my_file = '../places/' . $herman_is_the_best .'/cordinates.txt';
$handle = fopen($my_file, 'w') or die('Cannot open file:  '.$my_file); //implicitly creates file
$long = $data_arr[0];
$lati = $data_arr[1];
fwrite($handle, $long . "\r\n"
. $lati);

}

if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
$check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
if($check != false) {
    echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
    $uploadOk = 1;
} else {
    echo "File is not an image.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
}
// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($realtarget)) {
echo "Sorry, there was an error";
$uploadOk = 0;
 }
// Check file size
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000000) {
echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
$uploadOk = 0;
}
// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != 
"jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
$uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error 
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $realtarget)) 
{
    echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has 
been uploaded.";
} else {
    echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
} 
}

}


?>
```

The actual part where the file is uploaded is the same as used on the w3 tutorials. I added some code to make it make a place folder if there is not a place folder for that place from before and add the coordinates of the place in a txt file which is called coordinates.

The weird thing is that sometimes the file is uploaded to the parent directory and the place folder is not created. Other times the place folder is created and the image file is not uploaded at all.

So my question is what is going on here. I dont understand why it sometimes does one thing and other times dont with exactly the same picture.

```
  <form action="upload.php" id="uploadForm" class="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" style="width:100%; height:100%; font-size:400px">
   <input type="file" class="inputfile"  name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">

      <label for="fileToUpload" style="margin-left:35%; margin-top:8%; width:30%; height:16%; text-align:center"> <img style="width:70%; margin-top:6%"src="img/image.svg"></img></label>
   <input id="searchTextField" type="text" style="width:32%; height:50px; margin-left:33%; font-size:22pt; margin-top:30%" name="place">
    <script>
    function initialize() {
var options = {
types: ['(cities)']
 };

var input = document.getElementById('searchTextField');
var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>


     <input style="width:30%; height:8% ; font-size:23pt; margin-top:40%; 
 margin-left:35%" type="button" class="btn btn-success "  
 onclick="submitFirst();" id="connectWorld" value="Connect the world!"  
name="submit">
     <input id="submitbutton" type="submit" style="display:none"></input>       
  </form>
```

Does anybody have an idea of what is the issue here?

Comment: The code you copy/pasted does not look like valid PHP... Or is it just the real bad indentation?

Comment: it works sometimes so i guess its just ugly coding by me @Salketer

Comment: I've remade the indentation, seems all good to me... Only thing I see is if $_POST["place"]; is empty, then it will upload directly inside ../place/

Comment: Yeah that could happen but the form cant be submitted if the place field is not filled.. @Salketer

Comment: I'd clean the file up, as I said there's some fishy stuff... $results; does nothing... $data = print_r($results); is even worse. re-read your code, trim it to only the usefull and edit your question.

Comment: Should i add if(isset($_POST["submit"])) before trying to get the $_POST["place"]? @Salketer

Comment: There is absolutely no way to make sure that $_POST["submit"] being set means there is a place... You should always test the variable you want to access, not another...

Comment: Would the isset() function work to check that the place field is not empty or should i check if the place field is not equal to null? @Salketer

Comment: just checked the isset function it would work @Salketer

Comment: Edited the file btw

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

**HTML Form:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>File Upload with PHP</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="fileUpload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        Upload a File:
        <input type="file" name="file" id="fileToUpload">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload File Now" >
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**PHP Script:**

```
<?php
$currentDir = getcwd();
$uploadDirectory = "/uploads/";
$errors = []; // Store all foreseen and unforseen errors here

$fileExtensions = ['jpeg','jpg','png']; // Get all the file extensions

$fileName = $_FILES['myfile']['name'];
$fileSize = $_FILES['myfile']['size'];
$fileTmpName  = $_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name'];
$fileType = $_FILES['myfile']['type'];
$fileExtension = strtolower(end(explode('.',$fileName)));

$uploadPath = $currentDir . $uploadDirectory . basename($fileName); 

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    if (! in_array($fileExtension,$fileExtensions)) {
        $errors[] = "This file extension is not allowed. Please upload a JPEG or PNG file";
    }

    if ($fileSize > 2000000) {
        $errors[] = "This file is more than 2MB. Sorry, it has to be less than or equal to 2MB";
    }

    if (empty($errors)) {
        $didUpload = move_uploaded_file($fileTmpName, $uploadPath);

        if ($didUpload) {
            echo "The file " . basename($fileName) . " has been uploaded";
        } else {
            echo "An error occurred somewhere. Try again or contact the admin";
        }
    } else {
        foreach ($errors as $error) {
            echo $error . "These are the errors" . "\n";
        }
    }
}


?>
```

As an alternative to writing your own code consider using an open source image [PHP upload](http://cloudinary.com/documentation/php_image_upload) library that takes away the pain of having to write large amounts of code.